# Qt, use of "&" in tr

Tags: qt, tr

I'm going through the Qt5 Application [tutorial](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-mainwindows-application-example.html). In the creation of actions, I keep seeing the usage of "&" like the follwoing:

```
newAct = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/new.png"), tr("&New"), this)
...
openAct = new QAction(QIcon(":/images/open.png"), tr("&Open..."), this);
...
enter code exitAct = new QAction(tr("E&xit"), this);
...
```

I can't seem to find why these "&" are used, the Qt documentations on tr uses these notations without explaining what they are for. Further, when I deleted the "&" symbol, the resulting application doesn't seem to change at all.

Comment: If I remember correctly it sets the keyboard short cut for the action that the string describes. (eg in this case on Windows it would be ctrl-x)

Comment: Thanks all!Could you guys point me to where this is documented? I don't even know what keyword to search for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As far as `tr` is concerned `&` is just another character in the string and has no special meaning.

However it does have a special meaning to `QAction`: It sets the following character as the entry's shortcut within a menu, so when you have the "File" menu open, pressing the n key will activate the "New" entry, x will active "Exit" and so on. Depending on the OS, the character after the & may also be underlined (on Windows it's only underlined when you press the Alt key).

Comment: On Windows, at least, these shortcut keys don't only apply to menus. They can be for any widget. e.g. If you press 'O' and there's a button defined with "&Ok", you'll activate the button (as long as you're not in a widget that captures key presses like a text widget)

Answer (score 4):

`&` is used to indicate a character that should be used for the Alt-key shortcut for a given menu item. Assuming these actions are being put into a menu named `&File`, pressing <kbd>Alt-F</kbd>, then <kbd>N</kbd> would activate the `New` action.

Answer (score 0):

It's for shortcut (in many cases it's <kbd>Alt</kbd> and the character).

If you code doesn't have `&` it will be like this:

[image]

now if you have `&` before the key you want to use for shortcut, it will look like this:

[image]

Here I assume you already have these actions added to a menu as in the pictures above, and you also have `&` for the menu name, something like this:

```
fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu("&File");
```